# Working with an external programmer

Tags: web-development

Hello I want to build a website I found Programmer and He wants me I'll provide him a server with certain requirements.
Where is the best website  to rent a server ?
What kind of access he needs ?
How do I provide him access Without the ability to change things as payment information for your server ?

Comment: There are literally hundreds of options. To narrow them down, could you give a little more info on what type of site you plan building?  Specifically, what language you want it and what the function of the site will be?

Comment: You should give me detail about the type of website you plan to build, also you could ask the programmer which host he would refer to you, post the link here and let us inform you if this is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

As RandomBen alludes to, this is probably something you need to discuss with the programmer. Give him the requirements for the project, and he should be able to tell you what kind of hosting plan you need.

Most decent hosting plans allow you to create SFTP and shell accounts that are separate from your main billing account. With shared hosting, you may need to create a database for him via your web host's admin panel. In most cases, this is all the developer needs to develop and set up the site.

However, unless you're trying to develop a custom application or online service, you would probably be better off spending your money on a web designer and using an open source CMS. For most businesses, this is a better value than hiring a programmer/developer.

Answer (score 0):

I use HostMonster.com. It's a great website that offers a lot of hosting space / features at a pretty low price. ~$14/mo for everything. It includes a great control panel for everything you need.

All you need to do is make an FTP account for your programmer, give him the username/password and he can use third-party software to upload the files. You might have to do a little configuring for him (Such as creating an SQL database, but all of that is really simple).

Comment: What additional do you get for $14/mo? The standard plan on their site looks to be $6.95/mo (currently $5.95 for a promotion). At those prices, it looks pretty good assuming they have good uptimes and support. Though their site isn't all that well-designed. But if you don't need more than one shell account and only need a standard shared hosting plan, it doesn't look too bad.